# How to animate moving of the element from any part of the page to the center of the screen

Tags: html, css, angular, typescript

I need to animate moving of html element from any part of the page (not screen) to the center of the screen (not page).

I use Angular. So I need a solution using CSS animation or Angular animation.

I already wasted a lot of time and tried a lot of things but i have no idea.

Answer (score 1):

The answer greatly depends on the initial CSS of the element you're trying to animate.

Here's an example with a fixed position element, fixed height and width, using a simple transition. You just add / remove the class that centers the element. Impossible to tell whether this will work for you without you providing more info on the element in question.

```js
const centerButton = document.querySelector('#center-button');
const resetButton = document.querySelector('#reset-button');
const box = document.querySelector('#box');

centerButton.addEventListener('click', function () {
  box.classList.add('center');
});

resetButton.addEventListener('click', function () {
  box.classList.remove('center');
});
```

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#box {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: red;
  top: 40px;
  left: 40px;
}

#box.center {
  transition-property: top, left;
  transition-duration: 1s;
  top: calc(50vh - 50px);
  left: calc(50vw - 50px);
}
```

```html
<div id="box"></div>
<button id="center-button">CENTER</button>
<button id="reset-button">RESET</button>
```

Comment: cool! thats what i wanted. It moves to the center even when i scrolled, that was the point. I will use it. But is it possible to do it with keyframes. Just ineresting. I cant find the solution. With keyframes it moves to the center only when position of box is fixed or moves to the center of the page relative to the block itself.

Comment: Ok. Sorry. Your solution not working. It just seemed to me that its working, It moves to the center of the page when I haven't scrolled before. I mean it moves only to the top section of the page But i need the solution where block moves to the center of the screen whereever i scrolled the page, thats the point. Can you help me with this please?